# Ground bar on sub-panel

Tags: electrical

I just wanted to get confirmation on this.

Can I ground more than one wire per single slot/screw on a ground busbar in a sub panel?

Just to be clear, this is a sub panel with separate neutral and ground busbars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many electrical inspectors don't like seeing two wires in the same slot, *especially* when are unused slots.  They do seem to accept a few doubled up when they are all in use.  If they were serious about this "rule", they could insist on a ground bus extender—but I have never heard of that happening except in commercial (office) wiring.

Comment: I just bought a bigger ground busbar. I am not sure of local codes so I just figured I wouldn't risk it.

Comment: What an inspector "likes" to see is irrelevant. If it's allowed by code it's allowed. They can't make things up according to their whims, even in commercial installations.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey:  How, pray tell, would you get an inspector to change his "fails inspection" placard to something better?  Arguing with an inspector, even a complete imbecile, tends to waste a lot of time and money.

Comment: Very simple. Politely ask "Where can I find that in the code book? I never heard of that and I don't want to make a mistake like this again."......."Oh, it's not in the code book?". You do not have to "argue" to question an inspector's call. If they get that upset over being questioned then it is almost certain they are already on a power trip and need humbling.

Answer (score 2):

Consult the documentation for the panel or bar. Some allow it and some don't. And some jurisdictions won't allow it, even if the manufacturer allows it.

Answer (score 1):

Code is code, and pretty much every ground bar/panel I have seen in the past 25 years allows more than one grounding conductor, of the same size, per hole. Most up to three conductors. REGARDLESS of how many unused holes exist.

If an inspector can provide a written amendment disallowing it that is an entirely different story, but I doubt many of these local amendments exist.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the UL LISTING of the connections to the bar as was all ready mentioned the instructions will tell you.